# The law of the total third central moment

Tags: moments

On Wikipedia you can read in the article: **The law of total variance** as follows.

In probability theory, the law of total variance or variance decomposition formula or conditional variance formulas or law of iterated variances also known as Eve's law, states that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables on the same probability space, and the variance of $Y$ is finite, then

$$\displaystyle {\it Var} \left( Y \right) =E \left( {\it Var} \left( Y | X \right)  \right) +{\it Var} \left( E \left( Y | X \right)  \right)$$

The variance is also called the second central moment. Therefore, the law of total variance could also be called **the law of the total second central moment**. Is there also such a thing as **the law of the total third central moment** and **the law of the total fourth central moment**?

Answer (score 5):

It is a special case of the **Law of total cumulance** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_cumulance)). For the third central moment one obtains:

$\mu_3(X)= \operatorname{E}(\mu_3(X\mid Y))+\mu_3(\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y))
+3\operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y),\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y)).$

Comment: That's the law of total condition cumulances. How about low of total condition **moments**?